# My IF Functions aren't working

Tags: php, mysql, binary, hex

So,

I run a Minecraft server and have a website on separately hosted server. I use a bukkit plugin which sends a value to the database when the player joins. This stored as [BLOB - 1 B] (image below), which is a binary value, so I conevert it into hexadecimal then check its value. As its boolean it can either be 00 - false or 01 - true. But when using my if statements to check what the value is, if the value is 00 it still says online...

[image: My database]

But when I use this code on my webserver:

```
<form action="skript2.php" method="get">  
<input type="text" name="user" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Username" />
</form>
<?php
$uname = $_GET['user'];
$con=mysqli_connect("#####","#####","#####","#####");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `variables21` WHERE name='db_sdb.$uname.onlinemode'");
if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $val = $row['value'];
  $str = bin2hex("$val");
  echo "$str";
  if ($str = 01) {
    echo "<body bgcolor=\"green\">";
    echo "<font color=\"white\"><img src=\"https://minotar.net/helm/$uname/32\"> -- $uname is online!</font>";
  }
  if ($str = 00) {
    echo "<body bgcolor=\"red\">";
    echo "<font color=\"white\"><img src=\"https://minotar.net/helm/$uname/32\"> -- $uname is offline!</font>";
  }
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Details where they're ##### is private, such as passwords etc.

The connection works just fine, other wise it return an error saying can't connect.

So why aren't my IF functions working?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Because, you're assigning instead of comparing in many of your conditionals.

Comment: `=` is assignment, `==` is comparison.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys :)! Got it sorted. @NiettheDarkAbsol it was a general mistake on my part, got used to other programming languages...

Comment: You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: This is just a testing page, I have an automatic system in place where the user can't enter anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need == operator

```
 if ($str == 1) {

}
```

in Your view

```
if ($str == 1) {
    echo "<body bgcolor=\"green\">";
    echo "<font color=\"white\"><img src=\"https://minotar.net/helm/$uname/32\"> -- $uname is online!</font>";
  }
```

For ZERO you can use === operator

```
if ($str === 0) {
    echo "<body bgcolor=\"red\">";
    echo "<font color=\"white\"><img src=\"https://minotar.net/helm/$uname/32\"> -- $uname is offline!</font>";
  }
```

Comment: I'm an idiot! Thank you so much! Got use to VB.NET and just using = :) Thanks!

Comment: @nfell2009, Dont feel so bad :) Happy coding.

Comment: Another reason why VB.NET shouldn't exist anymore.

Comment: @DanAndrews :P It's not that bad of a language, I'm only 16. And learnt it for my school GCSE.

Answer (score 1):

A single `=` is binding a value to a variable -

```
if ($str = 01) {

}
```

A double `==` is a comparison operator, think of it as an 'is equal to'.

```
if ($str == 01) {

}
```

Comment: For those that habitually get these backwards, express them in the inverse: `01 = $str`. That will automatically fail since you can't make that kind of assignment.

Comment: Thanks! I'm so stupid sometimes xD